# Showing that a short exact sequence has a corresponding internal direct sum sequence

Tags: homological-algebra

> Let $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ be a short exact sequence of left $R$-modules.
>   If $M$ is any left $R$-module, prove that there are exact sequences
>   $$
>   0 \to A \oplus M \to B \oplus M \to C \to 0
> $$
>   and
>   $$
>   0 \to A \to B \oplus M \to C \oplus M \to 0.
> $$
>
> (Original picture of the problem [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6lNG.jpg).)

Proof Attempt: Let $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ be a short exact sequence of left $R$-modules. Let $M$ be any left $R$-Module. We want to adjoin $M$ to the corresponding exact sequence  $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$.

At this point I'm noticing that $A \cong A \oplus M$ and $A \oplus M$ and $B \cong B \oplus M$ would need to true for the corresponding exact sequences $0 \rightarrow A \oplus M \rightarrow B \oplus M \rightarrow C \rightarrow0$, $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \oplus M \rightarrow C \oplus M \rightarrow 0$.

However, my problem is trying to figure out how to implement the (internal) direct sums in the first exact sequence to get the two new exact sequences.

I would appreciate only advice and hints.

Comment: What you claim to notice, that $A\cong A\oplus M$ and $B\cong B\oplus M$ would need to be true, is incorrect. And what do you mean by "the (internal) direct sums in the first sequence? In the first sequence, $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$, I don't see any direct sums.

Comment: I think I was trying to state how to get from the first exact sequence the the two new ones with the direct sum. Note also that I didn't think that A being isomorphic to direct sum A and B would be true.

Comment: There is a more general version which is not more difficult : if 
$$0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$$ $$0\to A'\to B'\to C'\to 0$$
are two short exact sequence, then
$$0\to A\oplus A'\to B\oplus B'\to C\oplus C'\to 0$$
is also exact. Can you show it ? Can you see how this implies your claim ?